# Package multiple publish profiles .pubxml after a successful build in Jenkins CI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, jenkins, msbuild, publish-profiles

I'm using [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) for Continuous Integration.

Right now I have a job with this command in `Jenkins` in the command line arguments for a build step:

[image]

This is the command:

```
"%WORKSPACE%\OEVizion\ITVizion.OEVizion.Web\ITVizion.OEVizion.Web.csproj" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="IT Vizion - Web Deploy Package for a given domain.pubxml"
```

It works just fine, that is, the web deploy package (.zip) is created in the specified folder defined in the `.pubxml` file.

However what I'd like to do is to generate a `.zip` web deploy package for each of the .pubxml files that I have (right now 3) for this specific `ITVizion.OEVizion.Web.csproj` in a single shot\command.

With this I'd have multiple .zip packages with different settings ready to be deployed to different servers every time a commit is pushed to the repository and the project builds successfully.

Is this possible? How should I approach this?

Comment: While not exactly what you are asking, you can use the PackageWeb NuGet pkg http://sedodream.com/2012/03/14/PackageWebUpdatedAndVideoBelow.aspx to generate a pkg that has transforms inside of it. It also produces a .ps1 so you can invoke them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After posting the question I saw the way to go about this: Add ***multiple build steps***. One for each `.pubxml` file. That way the build process will run 3 times for the 3 publish profiles and you'll end up with 3 web deploy `.zip` packages at the end of the Job execution in Jenkins. Nice.

Answer (score 3):

The best practice is to build only once and then publish multiples times from the same build.  Here is a screenshot of how to set that up:

[image: Build once and publish 3 environments]

Comment: This is a great answer and it works for me, but it also doesn't feel as efficient as it could be. You're still creating a unique deploy package for each profile. Is there a way to use that same exact build object and only transform the required file/files? In other words, to have a single build output and all of the xformed files. When deploying, copy the build output and only the appropriate xformed files. That way we'd _really_ only have a single build artifact and only the unique files would have to be managed.

Comment: But, as it seems, the other 3 steps will still perform a build before publishing, or am I wrong?