# Using msbuild, how can I build once and then publish with multiple transform profiles?

Tags: msbuild, web-deployment

I have a .net solution that I can build with `msbuild` and successfully generate a deploy package with a `PublishProfile.pubxml` transform for deploying to a single web server.

I need to take that build and generate deploy packages for different environments, which are set up as transforms using various `.pubxml` profile files.

I know I could build each profile separately, and it'd be negligible risk of injecting a change into a build, but it's time and space that aren't necessary to consume. I would only end up keeping one of them anyway, and just copying the unique `web.config`s from each transform into their own deploy package's folder (sorry if this isn't clear, happy to clarify).

I'm looking for something like this pseudocode, which I know is syntactically incorrect but should get the point across:

```java
// step 1
msbuild myapp.csproj target=Build

// step 2
foreach ($profile in $profileList) {
  msbuild myapp.csproj outputdir="releaseDir/$profile" target=Publish publishProfile=$profile
}
```

I am working in a Jenkins context and can't use Visual Studio functions unless they're available as command-line options.

I've also tried desperately to get `msdeploy` to work, which I think might simplify some of this, but for the life of me I can't get it to work with the `tempAgent` option, which is really the only way I want to go in my environment. Details on that particular struggle [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66498253/error-unable-to-get-the-remote-environment-variable-windowsdirectory-using-ms)

Thanks in advance!

Update 1: [This post works well for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637727/package-multiple-publish-profiles-pubxml-after-a-successful-build-in-jenkins-ci), but as I say in a comment, it's still creating multiple deploy packages that take up a ton of space and aren't necessary. What I'd really like is a way to use a single build artifact and create multiple transforms of the Web.config files. Then on deploy, copy that build artifact and the appropriate config file. That would *really* be build-once/deploy-many!

FWIW, this is the code i came up with using the link above:

```
function Initialize-Build {
  $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
  $appName = 'myApp'
  $projsToBuild = 'Ui', 'DataService'
  $projPath = "$appName/$appName"
  $buildPath = 'obj/Release/Package/'
  $releasePath = 'Release-Packages'

  $commonArgs = '/p:Configuration=Release',
    '/nologo',
    '/verbosity:quiet'
}

function Invoke-Build {
  foreach ($proj in $projsToBuild) {
    $projName = $proj -eq 'Ui' ? 'WebUi' : $proj
    $p = "$projPath.$proj/$appName.$projName.csproj"

    $buildArgs = '/t:Clean,Build',
      '/p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False'

    Write-Output "Building $p"
    msbuild $p @commonArgs @buildArgs
    if ($LASTEXITCODE) { exit 1 }
  }
}

function Invoke-Transform {
  $xformArgs = "/p:deployOnBuild=True", "/p:Targets=Publish"

  foreach ($proj in $projsToBuild) {
    $p = "$projPath.$proj/$appName.$projName.csproj"

    $pubProfiles = 'Dev', 'QA', 'UAT', 'Prod'
    foreach ($prof in $pubProfiles) {  
      Write-Output "Building $p ($prof)"
      $pubProfileArg = "/p:PublishProfile=$prof"

      msbuild $p @commonArgs @xformArgs $pubProfileArg
      if ($LASTEXITCODE) { exit 1 }
    }  
  }
}

. Initialize-PrivLogBuild

Invoke-Build

Invoke-Transform
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized I wasn't really asking the right question. When I started searching for msbuild transform posts, I found a way to do what I need.

I landed on updating the .csproj files of the apps I'm building with an `AfterBuild` target.

There are 4 transforms required, each with their own .config file as the transform source. I was fortunate that these files had already been created by the application developer.

This is the code I ended up with, placed at the end of the .csproj file, inside the `</project>` tag. To reduce repetition of paths and filenames, I created `configDir` and `xformFile` properties. I like this pattern because it's easily scalable and generic!

```xml
<!-- all the rest of the .csproj above this -->
  <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml"
    AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v16.0/Web/Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <configDir>../../Release-Packages/configs</configDir>
      <xformFile>Web.config</xformFile>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <MakeDir Directories="$(configDir)" />
    <TransformXml Source="$(xformFile)"
                  Transform="Web.Dev.config"
                  Destination="$(configDir)/$(AssemblyName).$(xformFile).DEV" />
    <TransformXml Source="$(xformFile)"
                  Transform="Web.QA.config"
                  Destination="$(configDir)/$(AssemblyName).$(xformFile).QA" />
    <TransformXml Source="$(xformFile)"
                  Transform="Web.Prod.config"
                  Destination="$(configDir)/$(AssemblyName).$(xformFile).Prod" />
    <TransformXml Source="$(xformFile)"
                  Transform="Web.UAT.config"
                  Destination="$(configDir)/$(AssemblyName).$(xformFile).UAT" />                                 
  </Target>
</Project>
```

many thanks to these posts for lighting the way to this solution

- https://dougrathbone.com/blog/2011/09/14/using-custom-webconfig-transformations-in-msbuild
- [How do I use custom variables in MSBuild scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328431/how-do-i-use-custom-variables-in-msbuild-scripts)
- https://github.com/sayedihashimi/sayed-samples/blob/master/TransformMultipleWebConfigs/transform.proj
- https://www.locktar.nl/general/use-config-transforms-when-debugging-your-web-application/
- https://johan.driessen.se/posts/Applying-MSBuild-Config-Transformations-to-any-config-file-without-using-any-Visual-Studio-extensions/
- [Package multiple publish profiles .pubxml after a successful build in Jenkins CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637727/package-multiple-publish-profiles-pubxml-after-a-successful-build-in-jenkins-ci)
- https://bartlomiejmucha.com/en/blog/msbuild/how-to-extend-msbuild-publish-pipeline-to-apply-transform-files/